# Can't update Django 1.9 BooleanField

Tags: python, django

I have the following model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    force_password_change = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

For some reason I am not able to change the BooleanField at all. I would like to do this is in a view without a model form. Here's the output I get from the Django command line

```
>>> new_user = User.objects.get(username="bob")
>>> new_user
<User: bob>
>>> type(new_user)
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
>>> new_user.profile
<UserProfile: bob>
>>> type(new_user.profile)
<class 'accounts.models.UserProfile'>
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change = True
>>> new_user.save()
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>>
```

So what am I missing here? I'm sure it's something stupid, but any help would be great.

UPDATE:

Same issue if update the profile field.

```
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change = True
>>> new_user.profile.save()
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>>
```

UPDATE 2:

Tried this also:

```
>>>
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change = True
>>> new_user.profile.save()
>>> new_user = User.objects.get(pk=new_user.pk)
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>>
```

I guess the last bit of useful information I can provide is that I can fully change the force_password_change field through the admin panel. It's like the save action is not happening when I try user.profile.save()? But I'm not getting any errors that I notice.

Comment: You must save `new_user.profile`...

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. >>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change = True
>>> new_user.profile.save()
>>> new_user.profile.force_password_change
False
>>>

Comment: update your question, don't put code in comments.

Comment: Ok I updated it. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to see exactly. I didn't implement the save methods directly.

Comment: OK I have one more idea, I'll edit my answer..

Comment: MCVE needed  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what else can I provide that would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving the UserProfile object directly?

```
p = UserProfile.objects.get(user=new_user)
p.force_change_password = True
p.save()

print new_user.profile.force_change_password
```

Please excuse my brevity here... I'm typing this on a phone.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Any idea why it didn't work the other way?

Comment: I think replacing my first line with `p = new_user.profile` should work as well (however I can't double check this on mobile).

Comment: I think this section of the docs, especially the last 2 paragraphs, may be helpful - *Extending the existing User model* -https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model.